# Chrome Extension: Open new tab on startup

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

What I would like to do is to open a new tab (chrome://newtab) everytime Chrome starts.
My javascript code is working fine:

```
chrome.tabs.create({});
```

Everytime the script is executed the new tab opens, focuses and places the cursor in the address bar. The problem is, the code isn't always executed - only when no Chrome process was running before Chrome was started.

My second approach was to create an event listener so once executed chrome would know what to do when started. I've tried using this script:

```
chrome.windows.onCreated.addListener(function (Window window) {
    chrome.tabs.create({});
});
```

But this didn't work at all.

My manifest looks like this:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
   ...
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["newtab.js"],
    "persistent": false
  }
}
```

...
Therefore, what would be the correct way of realizing this?

Comment: when you say "only when no Chrome process was running before Chrome was started" do you mean that it doesn't work when there's already a chrome window open and you start a new one?

Comment: Only using the first method and `"persistent": true` in manifest, and killing all open chrome processes using taskkill did open a new tab. Closing and opening chrome again (normally) didnt't.

Answer (score 2):

`function (Window window) {` is invalid syntax.

`chrome.windows.onCreated.addListener(function() {
 chrome.tabs.create({})
})` will work instead.

However, this may not be what you want, as this will cause new tabs when new windows are created using Menu -> New window.

You can solve this by checking that the latest opened window is the only one.

```
chrome.windows.onCreated.addListener(function() {
 chrome.windows.getAll(function(windows) {
  if(windows.length == 1) {
   chrome.tabs.create({})
} }) })`
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured that out. No it wasn't exactly what I wanted but would be my first step. I now use this code:

`chrome.windows.onCreated.addListener(function (window) {
 chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow(window.id, function(tabs) {
  if (tabs[tabs.length-1].pinned) {
   chrome.tabs.create({});
  }
 });
});`

which works perfectly for me.